# $f$ is continuous such that $\int_0^t f(B_s)ds=0$ for all $t$ then $f(B_s)=0$ for all $s>0$, and $f\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a BM$^d$, $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^t f(B_s)ds=0$ for all $t>0.$ Show that $f(B_s)=0$ for all $s>0$, and conclude that $f\equiv 0$.

This is a problem from Rene Schilling's Brownian motion and we have the following solution.

By differentiation we get $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(B_s)ds=f(B_t)$ so that $f(B_t)=0$. We can assume that $f$ is positive and bounded, otherwise we could consider $f^{\pm}(B_t) \wedge c$ for some constant $c>0$. Now $E f(B_t)=0$ and we conclude from this that $f=0$.

My question is: How do we conclude from $Ef(B_t)=0$ that $f=0$? The expectation of a positive measurable function being $0$ implies that the function is a.s. $0$. But here the function is $f(B_t)$ not just $f$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is not identically $0$, there is some $x$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$.  WLOG
say $f(x) > 0$.  By continuity there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(y) > 0$ for $\|y - x\| < \epsilon$.  Now for any $t > 0$, $\mathbb P(\|B_t - x\| < \epsilon) > 0$, so $\mathbb P(f(B_t) > 0) > 0$.

Comment: I thought about the following proof. We have $\int f(y) \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-|y|^2 /2}(dy)=0$ so we must have $f(y) \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-|y|^2 /2}=0$ a.e. but by continuity everywhere and $e^{-|y|^2 /2}>0$ so $f=0$. But your proof is more elegant in using the BM property.